# E-OBS Dataset - Computation Problems

Tags: python, python-xarray, temperature, computation

I am trying to calculate some climatic indexes using [E-OBS daily data](https://surfobs.climate.copernicus.eu/dataaccess/access_eobs.php), and it requires some computation. I am using the xarray package for that. However, I am getting the following error message:

```
File "C:\Users\filip\anaconda3\envs\gis\lib\site-packages\xarray\backends\netCDF4_.py", line 486, in prepare_variable
        nc4_var = self.ds.createVariable(
      File "netCDF4\_netCDF4.pyx", line 2768, in netCDF4._netCDF4.Dataset.createVariable
      File "netCDF4\_netCDF4.pyx", line 3857, in netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable.__init__
      File "netCDF4\_netCDF4.pyx", line 1887, in netCDF4._netCDF4._ensure_nc_success
    RuntimeError: NetCDF: Invalid argument
```

A minimum reproducible example would be:

```
import xarray as xr

prec = 'D:/inputs/eobs/rr_ens_mean_0.1deg_reg_v24.0e.nc'
ds_p = xr.open_dataset(prec)
pp = ds_p.resample({'time': 'YS'}).sum(min_count=1, keep_attrs=True)
pp_mean = pp.mean('time', keep_attrs=True)


temp = 'D:/inputs/eobs/tg_ens_mean_0.1deg_reg_v24.0e.nc'
ds_t = xr.open_dataset(temp)
tp = ds_t.resample({'time': 'YS'}).mean(keep_attrs=True)
tp_mean = tp.mean('time', keep_attrs=True)

ind = (pp_mean['rr'] / tp_mean['tg']) * 10
ind.to_netcdf('D:/outputs/eobs/ind.nc')
```

Could you try and see if you get the same error message? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I don't get any error with this code, can you try with another python environment?

Comment: Hello Matteo, I created a new environment and installed xarray, netCDF4, h5netCDF and scipy. Still does not work. Strange thing is that with other datasets, this does not happen. I don't know what to do.

Comment: don't know, maybe the problem is in the libnetcdf or other libraries.

Comment: I wrote a script that does something very similar with eObs data. However, your resampling command looks like it uses an old version. This one works for me when resampling to monthly values and aggregating the values: ds.resample(time='M').sum()